# PHP: a simple string to date object conversion fails

Tags: php, date-conversion

I want to convert a string I fetched, into a date object so I can add/substract days to/from it. I tried several methods I read on the net but all failed and I'm completely lost (this should be easy!). This is one example:

```
echo '11: '.substr($content, 0, 10).'<br/>';
$theDay = new datetime(substr($content, 0, 10));
echo '2: '.$theDay->format('yyyy-mm-dd').'<br/>';
$theDay->modify('+1 day');
echo '21: '.$theDay->format('yyyy-mm-dd').'<br/>';
```

The output I got was:

```
11: 2016-02-10
2: 16161616-0202-1010
21: 16161616-0202-1111
```

The first line shows that the date structure is correct, the second line looks strange! and after adding 1 day, it looks as if it did add 1 day (11 instead of 10) but again it looks strange. What am I missing?

Comment: Try to read about format patterns again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got your format string messed up:

```
echo '11: '.substr($content, 0, 10).'<br/>';
$exDay = new datetime(substr($content, 0, 10));
echo '2: '.$exDay->format('Y-m-d').'<br/>';
$exDay->modify('+1 day');
echo '21: '.$exDay->format('Y-m-d').'<br/>';
```

Output:

```
11: 2016-02-10
2: 2016-02-10
21: 2016-02-11
```

See [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for a complete list of format characters. Relevant for this question are:

```
Y   A full numeric representation of a year, 4 digits
y   A two digit representation of a year
m   Numeric representation of a month, with leading zeros
d   Day of the month, 2 digits with leading zeros
```

I.e., you don't write `yyyy` for a 4 digit year, but instead `Y` (same goes for `m` and `d`).

Comment: so the problem was not the date conversion but the back to string conversion. I understand. Thanks